# as3isolib library IsoSprite does not have a hitTestObject nor hitTestPoint

Tags: actionscript-3

i having a problem where i cannot solve myself and i searched in the internet not be able to find the answer. So, i thought that this forum could help me. I am new in ActionScript 3 and currently i am developing a game where using as3isolib library and all features inside it.. But i am just wondering, why in the as3isolib especially in IsoSprite does not have hitTestObject nor hitTestPoint? How do i get those hitTest while using this IsoSprite? I want to get the collision between sprite 1 and sprite 2. But there is no hitTestObject nor hitTestPoint, how do i be able to get the collision detection then?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

May be I can help you!

I had the same problem Luckily I came across `isoBounds.intersects`

Example:

```
var intersects:Boolean = ISOSPRITE1.isoBounds.intersects(ISOSPRITE2);
```

this boolean give you a true or false if the iso sprite have a collision